# knife bootstrap "No such file or directory @ dir_initialize" from recipe that puts files to site-packages from local directory

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, directory, chef-infra, knife

I've got a default.rb file in the cookbook that I'm trying to bootstrap an ec2 instance with and I'm trying to move site-packages from my local virtual environment that I've been building with onto a server via this chef cookbook.

The reason for this is that our organization is very strict about how packages can be put onto production nodes, so I have to actually physically move over any libraries I want to use. There might very well be a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do and I'm very open for suggestions, but currently, the issue I'm running into is that I don't know how to reference the local directory in the foreach loop, so it keeps trying to reference the folder on the server, but it for some reason I guess hasn't been created yet even though my code to look there comes after the code to move it there.

Overall I'm confused by the error and would appreciate any explanation that can be given for why it's acting like the folder doesn't exist when the first block of code should have moved that folder there.

My code for this default.rb file is below:

```
#
# Cookbook:: <cookbook_name>
# Recipe:: default
#

include_recipe "yum-epel"

# install packages
for dir in ["connector_1", "connector_2", "connector_3", "json_logger", "connector_4", "site-packages"] do
  remote_directory "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/#{dir}" do
    source "app_packages/#{dir}"
    files_mode "0655"
    mode "0755"
  end
end

# install required site packages

Dir.foreach('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site-packages/') do |dir|
  next if not dir.end_with?('.dist-info')
    remote_directory "/usr/lib/python2.7/#{dir}" do
      source "app_packages/site-packages/#{dir}"
      files_mode "0655"
      mode "0755"
    end
end

remote_directory "/home/app-automation/bin/app_deployment" do
  source "app_deployment"
  files_owner "app-automation"
  files_group "app-automation"
  files_mode "0660"
  owner "app-automation"
  group "app-automation"
  mode "0770"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing ruby code with chef dsl. it behaves differently then you expect, as the ruby code that surrounds\wraps chef dsl gets executed at [compile time and not on convergence time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54178543/1184717) as you expect.

Comment: So would I have to have like two different recipes run one after the other instead of trying to do it all in one recipe?